# How can I make webpack skip a require

Tags: node.js, webpack

How can I make webpack skip occurences of

```
require('shelljs/global');
```

in my source files? I want to make a bundle of my source files but keep the `require('shelljs/global')` in the files and not bundle `shelljs/global`.

Comment: Soved my case by using target: 'node', https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html

Answer (score 35):

If you store the path in a variable then IgnorePlugin will not work. Though you still could do:

```
const myCustomModule = eval('require')(myCustomPath)
```

Comment: Simple and effective.

Comment: Warning: eval should be avoided. Only use it if you know and understand the risks. Otherwise, find another solution. Read up on Google or here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: For this specific use case I see no reason to worry and I claim that this is the cleanest solution, especially if the code is also going to be executed without Webpack as it works for both (in constrast to other suggestions here). Feeding eval with a 'require' literal does not introduce any risks.

Answer (score 24):

for new comers, on webpack 2+ the way to do this is like so:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + '/src/app',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
    externals: {
        'shelljs/globals': 'commonjs shelljs/global'
    }
};
```

the bundle will contain a verbatim require:

```
require('shelljs/global');
```

read on more supported formats [on webpack's config guide](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals) and some good examples [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/externals)

Comment: This will still rewrite the require, but Webpack will look externally for the dependency.

Answer (score 23):

You can use [Ignore Plugin (webpack 1)](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#ignoreplugin) / [Ignore plugin (webpack 2)](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/).

Add plugin in `webpack.config.js`:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/shelljs\/global/),
],
```

Answer (score 7):

If `require` is in the global namespace and this is why you want Webpack to ignore it, just do `window.require()`

Answer (score 7):

This should be a last resort option, but if you are certain that your JS file is always parsed by Webpack, and nothing else:

You could replace your `require()` calls with `__non_webpack_require__()`

Webpack will parse and convert any occurrence of this and output a normal `require()` call. This will only work if you are executing in NodeJS OR in a browser if you have a global require library available to trigger.

If webpack does not parse the file, and the script is run by something else, then your code will try to call the non-converted `__non_webpack_require__` which will fail. You could potentially write some code that checks earlier in your script if `__non_webpack_require__` exists as a function and if not, have it pass the call on to require.

However, this should be temporary, and only to just avoid the build errors, until you can replace it with something like Webpack's own dynamic imports.

Answer (score 3):

Here a trick

```js
const require = module[`require`].bind(module);
```

Note the use of a template string

Answer (score 1):

If some files contains nested requires and You want to ignore them, You can tell webpack to not do parsing for these specific files.
For example if *swiper.js* and *vue-quill-editor.js* had inner requires this would be how to ignore them.

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    noParse: [
     /swiper.js/,/quill/
    ],
```