# Error Cannot find module 'perf_hooks' when creating site with React-static

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I got the following error when creating a site with react-static create command:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'perf_hooks'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-static/lib/utils/index.js:45:19)
```

Just installed react-static using npm.

Answer (score 2):

[`perf_hooks`](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_performance_timing_api) is available since nodejs v8.5.

Check your nodejs version by `node -v`.

Answer (score 2):

My code had:

```
if (typeof performance === 'undefined') {
  // Older Node.js
  globals.performance = require('perf_hooks').performance;
} else {
  // Browser.
  globals.performance = performance;
}
```

to work around: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/28635 that hadn't been solved.

Since in that case the browser is taken care of trivially by the exposed global, I just hacked it to:

```
  globals.performance = eval('require')('perf_hooks').performance;
```

which makes webpack incapable of seeing the dependency as desired, as mentioned at: [How can I make webpack skip a require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34828722/how-can-i-make-webpack-skip-a-require)

Tested on react-scripts 4.0.3.

Comment: thank you! this helped me work around issue with webpack