# Why perf_hooks is not found in a webpack encore project? [require("perf_hooks") fails]

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, webpack-encore, ts-migrate

I want to migrate my Project from JS to TS and I'm using the ts-migrate-plugin from Airbnb.
https://github.com/airbnb/ts-migrate/tree/master/packages/ts-migrate-plugins

But I got the error:

```
fs and perf_hooks dependencies are not found.
```

After searching on StackOverflow I found a solution for `fs`

```
// webpack.config.js    
config.node = {
        fs: 'empty',
    };

module.exports = config;
```

**My Question is why `perf_hooks` are not beeing found, although `perf_hooks` are included in nodejs?** Something like:

```
// webpack.config.js
config.node = {
    fs: 'empty',
    perf_hooks: 'empty',
};

module.exports = config;
```

Does not fix the `perf_hooks` error:

```
This dependency was not found:

* perf_hooks in ./design/1/js/app.ts, ./node_modules/ts-migrate-server/build/src/utils/PerfTimer.js.
```

**More details:**

```
// app.ts
import path from 'path';
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import { tsIgnorePlugin } from 'ts-migrate-plugins';
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import { migrate, MigrateConfig } from 'ts-migrate-server';

// get input files folder
const inputDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'input');

// create new migration config and add ts-ignore plugin with empty options
const config = new MigrateConfig().addPlugin(tsIgnorePlugin, {});

// run migration
migrate({ rootDir: inputDir, config }).then(exitCode => {
    process.exit(exitCode);
});
```

Comment: to work with typescript you need to import `@types/node` this may be the problem, could you give more details as to what the error is (where is it from and its type)?

Comment: Adding @types/node does not help unfortunately. I put some more details in the description.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67288823/895245 I don't know why webpack won't see perf_hooks, but that might be a valid workaround.