# Webpack ignore import

Tags: webpack

I am importing a third-party module which imports another module:

`import fetch from "cross-fetch";`

I would like to tell Webpack to ignore/remove this import because the variable `fetch` already exists in global namespace. Is that possible?

Comment: So, are you trying to tell Webpack not to throw an error?

Comment: I just want to skip this import. `fetch` already exists in global namespace provided by the serverless enviroment I use. I want the third-party module NOT to import cross-fetch and instead use the already existent global variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make webpack skip a require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34828722/how-can-i-make-webpack-skip-a-require)

Comment: I tried to use IgnorePlugin but then the import statement is bundled and throws an exception. The import statement should be removed instead.

Comment: Did you try the highest voted answer's solution?: ```const myCustomModule = eval('require')(myCustomPath)```

Comment: This is not related to my problem. Also I am not doing the import, the third-party module does and even if, i cant use `eval` in my serverless environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify that some module is in the global env with [`externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/).

```js
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
    'cross-fetch': 'fetch' 
  }
};
```

Comment: wouldn't that should be `'cross-fetch': 'fetch'` instead. The left part match the import and the right part how to handle it and replace the import ???